# Alias not used in piped command - Git Bash

Tags: bash, colors, grep, pipe, alias

I'm using Git Bash on Windows, and especially the commands 'find' and 'grep' to locate files containing some text.

I've set the alias `grep='grep --color=auto'` which displays color just fine when used alone, however if I type:

`find . -iname "*.java" | xargs grep my_word`

the occurrences of my_word are NOT displayed in color. The colors only appear if I type:

`find . -iname "*.java" | xargs grep --color=auto my_word`

In other words, the alias seems not to be used on the right-hand side of a pipe.

Is this a normal behavior for an alias within a pipe ? I was unable to find an answer in the documentation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It is normal, but not because of the pipe.

`alias` defines alias for commands. It is not a *macro* substitution of all texts (e.g. in arguments and options.

In your case, the commands are: `find` and `xargs`. The command `xargs` will call directly the `grep` command, without passing from the original shell.

This behaviour is very useful. Various of the command you are running may be shell scripts, which may behave unexpectedly if you change the meaning of commands.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll define an alias <code>custom_find arg1 arg2</code> that will do something like <code>find . -iname "$arg1" | xargs grep "$arg2" --color=auto<code>.
I did not think of the alias interfering with other commands or scripts.

Comment: Or maybe the environment variable `GREP_OPTIONS` could help